# Is there any way to make checkboxes small/big in bootstrap 5.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

According to the docs you need to add the `.col-form-label-sm` and `.form-control-sm` classes (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/layout/#horizontal-form-label-sizing), however there doesn't seem to be anything similar for checkboxes (at least I haven't found anything in the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/checks-radios/#inline).

Specifically, I'm asking for which html/classes should be added to make the checkbox and label the same size (sm) as the email field:

```
<div class="row mb-3">
  <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="col-form-label-sm">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-check mb-3 offset-sm-1 required" style="position:relative; left: 1.5ex;">
        <input id="id_accept" name="accept" required="" tabindex="1" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ">
        <label for="id_accept" class="form-check-label ">
            Accept
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Corresponding example: https://codeply.com/p/p9iw6YQSeD

Comment: Have you tried adding `small` to check input field? `form-check-input small`

Comment: That makes them small, but the alignment is very off...

Comment: You can use `style` attribute to adjust its position

Comment: @Dexter yes, of course, but this question is more about built-in ways of doing it since they exist for regular inputs... (that is what I've done though - although instead of style attributes I have a fix-bs5.scss file ;-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on the codeply you shared. I do not know what `fix-bs5.scss` has. I am using bootstrap 5.2 with no additional CSS.

Here's with proper alignment

[image]

Just add `small` to the form wrapper div.

```html
...
    <div class="form-check small mb-3 offset-sm-1 required" style="position:relative; left: 1.5ex;">
        <!-- input and label -->
    </div>
....
```

### Original DOM structure

```
container
    ├── row/
    │   └── label/
    │       └── col-9/
    │           └── input
    └── row/
        └── div/
            ├── input
            └── label
```

[image]

### New structure

Instead of creating another `row`, you can place it under the existing input field.

```
container
    └── row/
        └── label/
            └── col-9/
                ├── input
                └── div/
                    ├── input
                    └── label
```

You do not need `style="position:relative; left: 1.5ex;"`

```html
<div class="container shadow min-vh-100 py-2">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <!-- col left -->
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email</label>
        <!-- col right -->
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="col-form-label-sm">
            <div class="form-check small mb-3 mt-2 required">
                <input id="id_accept" name="accept" required="" tabindex="1" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                <label for="id_accept" class="form-check-label">Accept</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Great and creative solution :-)  The solution is a little difficult to generate for auto-generated forms, but it made me realize that I needed to just revert to the grid - instead of trying to fix any mis-placement. Getting the .small in the right spot made it easier much easier to undo whatever BS was trying to do (I've updated the codeply if you're interested).